# How to apply for JWindow setAlwaysOnTop in Java? Where other JWindows are already also applied to setAlwaysOnTop

Tags: java, swing, jwindow

I have 3 layered window (like Gimp software). All my JWindow is assigned to setAlwaysOnTop for some display reasons with (`xrandr --output VGA --left-of LVDS`).

But I need one out of those three to be *"the super main always on top, whatever it moves or get drags it always stay as super on top"*. How can I set that one?

Toolbox.java << he should be the very very super on top always for any drag or etc

```
public class Toolbox extends JWindow
{
  public Toolbox() {
    ..
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
  }
}
```

Layers.java < normal as it is

```
public class Layers extends JWindow
{
  public Layers() {
    ...
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
  }
}
```

Drawing.java < normal as it is

```
public class Drawing extends JWindow
{
  public Drawing() {
    ...
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
  }
}

$ java -jar MyGimp.jar
- first it launch Drawing
- secondly it launch Layers
- Thirdly at the end it launch Toolbox
- But in Display I see only Drawing and Layers sometimes, but I never see Toolbox
```

When I launch the Drawing window then all my toolbox and layers window gets behind. But I want Toolbox window forever stay on top unless I close it. How to do that?

Comment: *"I have 3 layered window (like Gimp software)."*  Talk about starting with a recipe for disaster.  Use a `JDesktopPane` with multiple `JInternalFrame` instances instead.  Life will be a lot simpler for you, and the app. will be a lot less irritating to the end user.

Comment: I have 3 Heads 1PC. So my display is requires to split the JWindow in three screens. JDesktopPane can i do that?

Comment: *"I have 3 Heads*"  By 'Heads' do you mean 'monitors', or are you just a regular 3 headed monster/demon?

Comment: LOL. 3 Monitors like such: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mpde7.png   (but all running Java application one with Drawing, Another with Layers, Another with Toolbox or etc etc.

Comment: OK, no, `JDesktopPane` was designed to keep windows *together in one place* and therefore cannot help splitting them across different monitors.  For this situation, you are more likely to need one `JFrame` (the main app.) which owns a number of `JDialog` instances.

Comment: What is the result of [`isAlwaysOnTopSupported()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#isAlwaysOnTopSupported%28%29)?

Comment: @trashgod: TRUE (output always for three of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last component that is set to be on top overrides any previous components. What you do is just reset the Toolbox to be on top after you create Drawing.

Comment: That is correct the last component takes the priority for always on top. But which is not happening in my case, the Toolbox is always on top. From Drawing menu if i close and re-open it should come on top which is not happening.

Comment: When i launch java -jar MyGimp.jar. 1) it first launch drawing 2) then it execute layers 3) it run Toolbox 4) but in my display i always see the drawing only.